# Named pipe is using 100% CPU

Tags: python, unix

I'm starting the script with `./file.py < pipe >> logfile`
and the script is:

```
while True:
    try:
            I = raw_input().strip().split()
    except EOFError:
            continue
    doSomething()
```

How could I better handle named pipe? This script always run at 100% CPU and it need to be real-time so I cannot use `time.sleep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At EOF you will loop forever getting yet another EOF.  No more input will be done after EOF.

EOF does not mean a "gap" in the data.  It means the named socket was disconnected and can no longer be used.

If you want "real-time" data, you have to read individual bytes from the socket until you get a complete "message".  Perhaps a message ends with a `'\n'`.  You can't use `raw_input`.

You have to use `sys.stdin.read(1)` to get bytes.

Pipes, BTW, are buffered.  So you won't get real-time anything.  If you want "real-time" you have to use UDP sockets, not TCP pipes.

Answer (score 2):

"Real-time" (since it's obviously "soft" real-time given you have multiple processes going, not "hard" real-time!) does not mean "you **cannot** use `time.sleep`": even a tiny amount of sleep will make things a little bit better -- try adding a `time.sleep(0.01)` in your loop, just to give other processes a better chance to run.  The lack of sleep may actually be making you take a *longer* time by giving other processes very little chance to fill the pipe!

Beyond this, @S.Lott has it just right: for "real-timeoid" behavior, you have to read from `sys.stdin` (though it probably need not be a byte at a time, depending on the platform: typically `sys.stdin.read(1024)` will read **up to** 1024 bytes, when `sys.stdin` is a pipe or other "raw" as opposed to "cooked" FD, returning however many bytes are in the pipe, if <100, rather than waiting -- you can set the FD to non-blocking to help assure that) directly, and perform string manipulation (e.g. to put lines together, strip them, etc) later in your code.